# SignalR: почему при добавлении подключения в группу в первом хабе группу не видно во втором?

Tags: c#, signalr

Вся суть вопроса в заголовке.
Пример:

```
public class FirstHub : Hub
{
  public void Foo()
  {
    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "foo");
  }
}

public class SecondHub : Hub<IEvents>
{
  public void Bar()
  {
    Clients.Group("foo").TestEvent("Hello, world"); // Не сработает на клиенте
  }
}
```

Comment: Это скорее предложение. Каждый хаб регистрирует отдельно и считается самостоятельной точкой подключения. Соответственно и пользователи с группами будут разные.

Comment: Ну вроде как пишут, что обращения к хабам (всем) происходит по одному адресу

Comment: Посмотри [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#configure-the-project-to-use-signalr) на часть с регистрацией самого хаба в методе Configure. Это имел в виду.

Comment: Ах да, забыл добавить, что использую Selft.Host